# Is there any application of topology to deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, topology

Is there any application of topology (as in math discipline) to deep learning? If so, what are some examples?

Comment: See [A Topology Layer for Machine Learning](http://ai.stanford.edu/blog/topologylayer/) by Rickard Brüel Gabrielsson.